# For loop in JADE

Tags: html, loops, pug

I am busy learning the templating language JADE, and I can't seem to figure out how to do `for` loops.

Currently I have the following code:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
p #{var}
- }
```

I'm trying to output the value of `var` in a `p` tag ten times.

Answer (score 1):

The word `var` is a keyword in Javascript. Jade is written in Javascript. There is no variable, `var`, the definition to create variables is

```
var [NameOfMyVariable] = [TheDataIntoMyVariable];
```

This being so, what you intend is to obtain an iteration of a variable. which in this case is `i`,

```
- for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  p #{i}
- }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the jade syntax to loop over an array: http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/

for instance:

`ul
  each val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    li= val`

and as Alejo already said, you cannot use `var` as a variable in jade, because it's a JavaScript keyword.